# Update specific rows in Oracle using the count from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update some records in one table (street) with a count from another table (house). I am trying to update the house_count in the street table with the correct number of houses on that street. I only want to update the records that are incorrect. I have been able to do this is MSSQL using the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE street
(
name varchar(255),
house_count int
);

Create table house
(
id varchar(255),
street_name varchar(255)
);

insert into street values ('oak',1)
insert into street values ('maple',2)
insert into street values ('birch',4)
insert into street values ('walnut',1)

insert into house values (1,'oak')   
insert into house values (2,'oak')
insert into house values (1,'maple')
insert into house values (2,'maple')
insert into house values (1,'birch')
insert into house values (2,'birch')
insert into house values (3,'birch')
insert into house values (1,'walnut')

update s set s.house_count= hc.ActualCount
from street s
inner join
(select s.name, count(s.name) as 'ActualCount', s.house_count
from street s
inner join house h on s.name=h.street_name
group by s.name, s.house_count
having count(s.name) <> s.house_count) hc ON s.name=hc.name
where s.name=hc.name
```

I have a need to do something similar in Oracle but have ran into issues. From what I have found the join is not possible in Oracle but I am having a hard time getting something that will work. Any help in getting something like this to work in Oracle is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update street
    set house_count = (select count(s.name)
                       from house h
                       where street.name = h.street_name
                      );
```

This is a little different from your approach, because it will update *all* streets, even when the count does not change.  There is no performance advantage using a subquery in trying to prevent the update.

EDIT:

This should solve the problem with the apartment streets versus house streets:

```
update street
    set house_count = (select count(s.name)
                       from house h
                       where street.name = h.street_name
                      )
    where exists (select 1 from house h where street.name = h.street_name);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to simplify my example to make it easier to explain but there are other tables involved that have records in the street table. For example an apartment table that also references the street table. In my scenario the house count could be apartments but houses and apartments will never be on the same street. I am only concerned in updating the number of houses and want to leave the apartment streets alone. By running the statement in this way it will update all the records. Any thoughts on how to update the incorrect records or at least just the house streets?